# Why is the result of sizeof implementation defined?

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

In C99, §6.5.3.4:

> 2 The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand,
>   which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. ...
>
> 4 The value of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (an
>   unsigned integer type) is `size_t`, defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other
>   headers).

In C++14, §5.3.3:

> 1 The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes in the object
>   representation of its operand. ... The result of sizeof applied to any
>   other fundamental type (3.9.1) is implementation-defined.

The only guaranteed values are `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(unsigned char)` and `sizeof(signed char)` which is one.

However, "the number of bytes in the object representation" seems pretty iron-clad to me. For example, in C99 §6.2.6.1:

> 4 Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type
>   consist of *n* × **CHAR_BIT** bits, where *n* is the size of an object
>   of that type, in bytes. ...

So why is it implementation-defined if it seems pretty defined?

---

Many of you seem to be misinterpretating my question. I never claimed that:

A) The size of types are defined or the same on all systems,

B) implementation-defined means it can return "random values"

What I'm getting at here is that `n * CHAR_BITS` is a fixed formula. The formula itself can't changed between implementations. Yes, an `int` may be 4 bytes or 8 bytes. I get that. But between **all** implementations, the value must `n * CHAR_BITS`.

Comment: Maybe because the sizes of all other types are implementation defined? Not sure.

Comment: For example, `int` and related types may be different sizes (32 bits or 64 bits). Also padding in structs/classes can be different on different platforms.

Comment: @melak47 The rules will still constrain the implementation to output the correct number of bytes regardless. Making it implementation-defined would allow an implementation to output a bogus number (but unlikely).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Padding bits are "unspecified" not "implementation-defined".

Comment: note "...where n is the size of an object of that type, in bytes. ..." ie it has to be nxCHAR_BIT, but the size of the object itself is implementation defined

Comment: "The result of sizeof applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is implementation-defined". Obviously if the size of a fundamental type is implementation defined, then the result of applying `sizeof` to it is implementation defined.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper Incorrect on both accounts. A conforming implementation can't lie about `sizeof`. And padding bits are not unspecified. Try reading the standard you quoted instead of blindly copying and pasting.

Comment: "implementation-defined" doesn't mean a compiler can return random numbers. The results are still constrained by the language standard. It just means 1) different implementations can return different values and 2) they have to document what they do.

Comment: RE your edit: you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of the language. I suggest you read a book before trying to act like a language lawyer. "Implementation-defined" means exactly what it says on the tin: the widths of the types will vary between implementations. So how can the value of `sizeof` not be implementation-defined? Please use your god given brain!

Comment: Reminds me of an old prof of mine. He always gave very generalised examples. So we once asked him for a specific example with a fixed value. His resonse: "Ok, so let's have a fixed value called `n` ...". (We never asked again)

Comment: `n * CHAR_BITS` would represent the number of `bits` - that is not what sizeof yields - it is just *n*.

Comment: To expand on what @melpomene said: "Implemenation defined" means that the implementation can have different behavior from other implementations. That behavior may still have constraints imposed by the standard. Implementation defined behavior is supposed to be documented.   "Unspecified behavior" means that the behavior may be different between different implementations and does not have to be documented.  Unspecified behavior also usually has constraints imposed by the standard.  "Undefined behavior" means the implementation can do whatever.

Answer (score 12):

The result of `sizeof` is implementation defined because the size of the various basic types are implementation defined.  The only guarantees we have on the size of the types in C++ is that

```
sizeof(char) = 1 and sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= 
sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)
```

And that each type has a minimum value it must support C11 [Annex E (informative) Implementation limits]/1

> [...]The minimum magnitudes shown shall be replaced by implementation-defined magnitudes with the same sign.[...]

```
#define CHAR_BIT    8
#define CHAR_MAX    UCHAR_MAX or SCHAR_MAX
#define CHAR_MIN    0 or SCHAR_MIN
#define INT_MAX     +32767
#define INT_MIN     -32767
#define LONG_MAX    +2147483647
#define LONG_MIN    -2147483647
#define LLONG_MAX   +9223372036854775807
#define LLONG_MIN   -9223372036854775807
#define MB_LEN_MAX  1
#define SCHAR_MAX   +127
#define SCHAR_MIN   -127
#define SHRT_MAX    +32767
#define SHRT_MIN    -32767
#define UCHAR_MAX   255
#define USHRT_MAX   65535
#define UINT_MAX    65535
#define ULONG_MAX   4294967295
#define ULLONG_MAX  18446744073709551615
```

So per the standard a `int` has to be able to store a number that could be stored in 16 bits but it can be bigger and on most of today's systems it is 32 bits.

> What I'm getting at here is that `n * CHAR_BITS` is a fixed formula. The formula itself can't changed between implementations. Yes, an int may be 4 bytes or 8 bytes. I get that. But between all implementations, the value must `n * CHAR_BITS`.

You are correct but `n` is defined per C99 §6.2.6.1 as

> where `n` is the **size of an object** of that type

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So the formula may be fixed but `n` is not fixed and different implementations on the same system can use a different value of `n`.

Answer (score 5):

The result of `sizeof` *is not* implementation defined.  The standard does not say that; it says:

> The ***value*** of the result is implementation-defined, [...]

That is semantically different.  The result of `sizeof` is well defined:

> [...] the size (in bytes) of its operand [...]

Both the bit width of a byte in this context and the number of bytes in non `char` types *is* implementation defined.

Comment: Note I say "in this context" because in many contexts byte is 8 bits (disk capacity for example).

Answer (score 1):

Because the sizes of basic types are defined in terms of efficiency, not in terms of exact number of bits. An "int" must be something that the CPU can manipulate efficiently. For most modern systems, this quantity turns out to be 32 bits (or 64 bits). For older systems, it was quite often 16 bits. However, if a 35 bits CPU were to exist, an int on such a system would be 35 bits. In other words, C++ does not apply a penalty to enforce a bit-width a CPU might not support at all.

Of course, one could argue that notions of exotic bit widths for basic types have been overtaken by history. I cannot think of any modern CPU that does not support the standard set of 8, 16, and 32 bits (feel free to disagree with this statement, but at least be so kind to give an example!), and 64 bits is also pretty common (and not a big deal to support in software if hardware support is unavailable).

Arguably the C++ language has already moved away from having variable numbers of bits for char; as far as I know, u8"..." converts to char *, but the unicode specification demands that u8 is encoded in 8 bits.

If a char of 8 bits is size 1, then an int of 32 bits is size 4. If a char of 16 bits is size 1, then an int of 32 bits is only size 2. Both situations are equally valid in C++, if such sizes happen to be good choices for their respective hardware.

Comment: Nothing stops a UTF-8 encoded character string from being stored in 9-bit bytes. Of course, no individual code could be greater than 255 -- in fact, the maximum value in UTF-8 encoding is 244 -- but those values could be stored in bytes of any width greater than or equal to 8.

Answer (score -1):

> Padding bits are "unspecified" not "implementation-defined".

Wrong. Very, very wrong. The **values** of padding bytes are unspecified.  The intention here is that the values of these bits may represent trap values, but not necessarily.

The standard tells you `sizeof` returns `bytes * CHAR_BITS`, but doesn't specify a size (other than the exact-width types). The number of bytes a type occupies is implementation-defined, hence `sizeof` must be as well.

Implementation-defined is decribed as:

> unspecified value where each implementation documents how the choice
>   is made

Comment: This "answer" refers to a comment rather than the question, so should be posted as a comment not an answer.  `sizeof` return the size in terms of the number of `char` sized units - not `bytes * CHAR_BITS ` that would be the number or *bits*.  Perhaps you meant `bits / CHAR_BITS`?

Comment: @Clifford Uh no. "where n is the size of an object of that type, in bytes". It's right in the question.

Comment: @Clifford And explain to me how this isn't an answer. I correct OP on his misunderstanding and explain why `sizeof` is implementation-defined. That's exactly what the other answer is doing, just in more words.

Comment: The quoted text is not in the question, it is in a comment.  That and the paragraph following it are a comment on a comment, not an answer.  The rest is an answer.

Answer (score -1):

When you declare a new variable in example like this:

size_t a;

it will be equal with this:

```
unsigned short int a; // unsigned short a
```

On 32-bit computers size of the integer number (int) is 4 bytes.
Size of the short int is 2 bytes.

In C programming languange 'size_t' is the return type of the 'sizeof()' operator.When you use 'sizeof()' operator he will give you the size of the object.Argument of the 'sizeof()' must be an l-value type. Size of the element(object) cannot be a negative number and it must be an integer.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the standard requires `size_t` to be equivalent to `unsigned short int`? In most modern implementations, that is not even the case. And even if it were, it would be missing the point of this question, which is asking about the requirements in the language standard.